# What does NAME="blah" do in udev rules?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

Quoting `man 7 udev`

> NAME The name to use for a network interface... The name of a device node **cannot** be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.

From the wording, I am not sure what an assignment like `NAME="blah"` can do, if it cannot change the name of a device node.

And, my understanding is, by the time `udevd` receives the 'add' uevent from kernel, the relevant device node is already created under `/dev`, it can only tweak its properties such as permissions, or add symlinks. So what does `NAME` assignment do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

As it says: it can be used to set the name of **a network interface**, for network interfaces don't have device nodes associated with them.

(`/dev/net/tun` is not a *network interface*: it is a control interface for creating, configuring and destroying `tun*` or `tap*` network interfaces.)

But if your system supports `/etc/systemd/network/*.link` files, you could use those to rename your network interfaces with a more forgiving configuration syntax: unlike with udev rules, messing up the syntax of a `*.link` file should not be able to cause problems in the set-up of any unrelated devices.

---

Back when RHEL 6 was new, it was actually possible to use the `NAME="blah"` assignment to change the actual names of the device nodes. But this apparently turned out to be more trouble than it was worth, so this feature was nerfed as the kernel development went on.